# Shopify display Most viewed Products via API

Tags: google-analytics-api, shopify

I've been working to develop a shopify **app**. I've used **Shopify API** to display data like, Top Products, Top Customers etc.

Now i want to display products based on their **number of views** in ascending or descending order.

How can i achieve that using Shopify API?
If It is not possible via API and I need to integrate **Google Analytics** to it, then is there any guide that can tell me how to get products views data from the store?

Any help would save my day.

Comment: Not sure about how to integrate into a shopify app, But to get you started your server can always query the [Analytics Reporting API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/). If shopify allows you to order the results by an arbitrary metric then simply have your server occasionally query your Analytics Account for the desired [metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets)

Comment: Hi, I would suggest you a simple php ajax script that will the view and store in a database including the domain name and product sku.  Later you can use that database to determine which product got how much view. and display most viewed product for a domain ( shopify store ).

Comment: So shopify don't provide it in the api?